# Controller method not found while using link_to_action helper function

Tags: laravel

This is my controller:

```
class UserPostController extends \BaseController {


    public function index($user_id)
    {

        $posts = Post::with('user')->find($user_id)->paginate(20);


        return View::make('users.posts.index', compact('posts'));


    }


}
```

These are my routes:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('users.posts', 'UserPostController');
```

This is my view:

```
{{ link_to_action('UserPostController@index', 'Show posts', array( Auth::user()->id )) }}
```

I wrote composer dump-autoload after getting the error, but it still doesn't work.

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Controller method not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::resource('users.posts', 'UserPostController');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

Laravel takes the first item that seems to match the route, so you need to put the routes for users.posts before users.